# C# output SQL Server Messages to text file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am new to C#, so please bear with me as I have inherited a script that I'm attempting to tweak.

I want to get the output of SQL PRINT/RAISERROR statements to show up in a log file that has been declared in another part of the script.

This is my method I'm calling:

```
public void ProcessData(string StoredProcedure, int StartDate, int EndDate, string Directory, string LogFileNameAndPath)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = null;
        SqlParameter sqlParameter = null;
       // String outputText = null;

        try
        {
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
            sqlConnection.Open();

            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.CommandText = StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
            sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

            sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@StartDt", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlParameter.Value = StartDate;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

            sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@EndDt", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlParameter.Value = EndDate;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

            sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@stringDirs", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlParameter.Value = Directory;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

            sqlConnection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(OnInfoMessage);
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            throw sqlEx;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlConnection != null)
            {
                if (sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    sqlConnection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the info handler method:

```
    public void OnInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs args)//, String LogFileNameAndPath)
    {
        foreach (SqlError err in args.Errors)
        {

            //File.AppendAllText(LogFileNameAndPath, err.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", err.Message);
            //return err.Message;
          //"The {0} has received a severity {1}, state {2} error number {3}\n" +
         // "on line {4} of procedure {5} on server {6}:\n{7}",
         //  err.Source, err.Class, err.State, err.Number, err.LineNumber,
         //  err.Procedure, err.Server, err.Message);
        }
    }
```

Instead of outputting to the Console, I want to write it to the LogFileNameAndPath variable via the "File.AppendAllText(LogFileNameAndPath, err.Message)"; however, I have looked at many posts over the web and NOBODY provides a solution.  Is there a way to do this?  Please be kind.  Thanks!

===========================================================================

[ADDED 2015-07-27 1606 EDT]
If I change this line from:

```
sqlConnection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(OnInfoMessage);
```

... to ...

```
sqlConnection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(OnInfoMessage(LogFileNameAndPath));
```

... it fails to compile.  **How does this get passed to the method?**

Here's the new method:

```
    public void OnInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs args, String LogFileNameAndPath)
    {
        foreach (SqlError err in args.Errors)
        {

            File.AppendAllText(@LogFileNameAndPath, err.Message);
            //Console.WriteLine("{0}", err.Message);
          }
    }
```

Comment: Is there some reason that uncommenting the existing `File.AppendAllText()` call doesn't work?  Are you receiving a specific error?

Comment: if I uncomment this, then the sqlConnection.InfoMessage variable will not allow me to pass a parameter to the void method it calls.  How can I do this?

Comment: you can't do that as event handlers are specific methods.. you can try extensions maybe, or define a global variable and pass the path to it then use it the event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try to pass the log file name into the event handler, you should have the log file name be defined elsewhere, and visible inside the event handler.  For example:

```
public class SqlHandler
{
    private readonly string m_LogFileNameAndPath = @"C:\log.txt";
    // or get it from AppConfig, as noted by FirebladeDan

    public void ProcessData() { /*...*/ }

    public void OnInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        foreach(var err in args.Errors)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(m_LogFileNameAndPath, err.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

It's also worth noting that you can still use a logging library (Log4Net, NLog, etc.) with a custom file, by telling the library which file to log to.

Answer (score 2):

While writing straight to a file may work for you (see @FirebladeDan's answer for that), I would highly recommend using an existing logging library for performance reasons.

Log4Net is a common suggestion, and [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8245/A-Brief-Introduction-to-the-log-net-logging-librar) should be a good start for you. Log4Net has some nice features that help you such as the ability via the App.Config/Web.Config files to configure logging at run-time, so that you can change the logging level (how detailed) based upon the configuration without a recompile.

Hopefully this gets you on the right path, and good luck to you!

EDIT:

Based upon your updated statements, this option may be what you need.

```
// use a variable to store the path.
private string logFileNameAndPath;

public void ProcessData(string StoredProcedure, int StartDate, int EndDate, string Directory, string LogFileNameAndPath)
{
   // Store the parameter that was passed in as the variable.
   this.logFileNameAndPath = LogFileNameAndPath;
   /* Do query setup work here*/
   sqlConnection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(OnInfoMessage);
   sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

public void OnInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (SqlError err in args.Errors)
    {
        // Use the variable to indicate where to log to.
        File.AppendAllText(this.logFileNameAndPath, err.Message);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps get you across the finish line.

Comment: I second that, using a logging framework like Log4Net is much better.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but this is going to be ran internally by another department, and I want to keep it as simple as possible for anybody else to make edits to this.  This is why I must remain with utilizing the existing log file.

Comment: See my update for an option to do it without log4net by storing the path in a variable within the class being called.

Answer (score 1):

```
File.AppendAllText(@"pathgoeshere", err.Message);
```

Added: Below is how to get the value using a key from your AppConfig

```
String LogFileNameandPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keynamegoeshere"]);
```

Pass LogFileNameandPath into your method **Don't forget to add your references

Comment: I want the ability to have the log filename and path determined by the key in the App.config file.  This will not work, see my new edit to show what I'm talking about